# Using std::atomic<T*> as a fence

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic

I've written a Resource class below for an async resource manager. During load, a Resource object is created with the default resource (e.g. a black texture) so that the main thread that will use the Resource doesn't have to wait, even though it's a blank resource. As soon as the loading is finished, the loader thread will call setResource() and set the underlying resource to the newly loaded one. But there is also ownership involved. So when the loading is finished, the newly assigned resource will be owned by Resource class so that it can be released when Resource is destroyed or another setResource is called because file on disk has changed and needed reloading.

```
template <typename T>
class Resource {
 protected:
  // Underlying object
  std::atomic<T*> resource;

  // Do I own resource
  bool isOwner;

  // Id of resource for faster mapping
  uint64_t id;

  // Name
  std::string name;

 public:
  Resource(T* res) : resource(res), isOwner(false), id(0), name("non") {}

  Resource(std::unique_ptr<T>&& res)
      : resource(res.release()), isOwner(true), id(0), name("non") {}

  ~Resource() {
    if (isOwner) delete resource.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
  }

  Resource(Resource&&) = default;

  Resource(const Resource&) = delete;
  Resource& operator=(const Resource&) = delete;

  T* getResource() { 
    return resource.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
  }

  void setResource(T* res, bool own = false) {
    if (isOwner) { 
      delete resource.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    }

    isOwner = own;
    resource.store(res, std::memory_order_release);
  }

  void setResource(std::unique_ptr<T>&& res) {
    if (isOwner) { 
      delete resource.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    }

    isOwner = true;
    resource.store(res.release(), std::memory_order_release);
  }

  void setId(uint64_t idd) { id = idd; }
};
```

Is there a data race on isOwner or does atomic.store() act as a fence in that case? Or should I change the whole ownership approach and just use `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>` which I don't know if doable?

Comment: hm...maybe consider the "null object pattern" and "swap" when loaded

Comment: Aren't you reimplementing `std::unique_ptr<>` here, with a simple `swap` being your `setResource`?

Answer (score 1):

When the code does `delete resource.load(std::memory_order_acquire);` another thread may still be using the resource, so this is a race condition.

One simple work-around is to never delete the existing resource. You can have that black texture as a global object with static storage duration that is alive during entire execution of your application.

Another, is for `getResource` to return a `std::shared_ptr<T>` (by value), so that the old resource gets automatically destroyed when its last user disposes of it. E.g.:

```
struct NullDeleter {
    template<class T>
    void operator()(T const&) {}
};

template<typename T>
class Resource {
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<T> resource;
public:
    Resource(T& res) : resource(&res, NullDeleter{}) {}

    Resource(std::shared_ptr<T> const& res) : resource(res) {}

    std::shared_ptr<T> getResource() {
        return atomic_load(&resource);
    }

    void setResource(std::shared_ptr<T> const& res) {
        atomic_store(&resource, res);
    }
};
```